# la variable no fue inicializada

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy programando este codigo para un proyecto de la universidad, pero no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.
En la parte final del codigo es donde me da el problema, cuando el programa imprime el total, porque para que me de el resultado necesito usar un dato que se ingreso en la variable "menores_edad", pero este dato se ingreso dentro del if que esta en el principio, pero cuando lo uso en esa parte me dice que la variable no fue inicializada. No encontré como resolverlo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Parque_de_diversiones {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);    
      String nombre_reserva, telefono;
      int total_personas, menores_edad;
      boolean montaña_rusa, toboganes, paseo_bote, mirador;
      double total = 0, precio_montaña = 150, precio_toboganes = 120, precio_paseo = 400, precio_mirador = 170, descuento;
      
        System.out.print("¿Cuál es su nombre? ");
          nombre_reserva = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Ingrese su número de telefono ");
          telefono = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("¿Cuántas personas iran al viaje? ");
        System.out.println("(Las reservas tiene un limite de 20 personas por pago)");
          total_personas = leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿LLevara niños a su viaje? ");
        System.out.println("Indique <true> para SI y <false> para NO" );
          boolean niños = leer.nextBoolean();
          
          if(niños == true){
            System.out.print("¿Cuantos niños vendrán al viaje? ");
            menores_edad = leer.nextInt();     
          }
         
        System.out.println("Indique a que atracciones subira durante su viaje ");
        System.out.println("Indique <true> para SI y <false> para NO ");
        System.out.print("Montaña rusa: ");
          montaña_rusa = leer.nextBoolean();
        System.out.print("Toboganes: ");
          toboganes = leer.nextBoolean();
        System.out.print("Paseo en bote en mar abierto: ");
          paseo_bote = leer.nextBoolean();
        System.out.print("Mirador: ");
          mirador = leer.nextBoolean();
            
            if(montaña_rusa == true){
              total = total + precio_montaña;
            }
            if(toboganes == true){
              total = total + precio_toboganes;
            }
            if(paseo_bote == true){
              total = total + precio_paseo;
            }
            if(mirador == true){
              total = total + precio_mirador;  
            }
            
            total = total * total_personas;
                    
          System.out.println("¿Se hospedará en nuestras instalaciones?");
          System.out.println("Indique <true> para SI y <false> para NO");
            boolean reserva = leer.nextBoolean(); 
          
            if(reserva == true && niños == true){
                if(niños == true && menores_edad >= 10){
                  System.out.println("Gracias por hacer su reserva " + nombre_reserva);
                  System.out.println("El costo total, por todas las personas de su paquete, para las atracciones que ha elegido es de: " + total);
                  System.out.println("Usted tiene un 20% de descuento");
                  System.out.println("Más un 5% sobre el descuento");
                    descuento = total * 0.20;
                    total = total - descuento;
                    descuento = total * 0.05;
                    total = total - descuento;
                  System.out.println("El costo final de su viaje por las atracciones sera de: " + total);
              
                }else{
                  System.out.println("Gracias por hacer su reserva " + nombre_reserva);
                  System.out.println("El costo total, por todas las personas de su paquete, para las atracciones que ha elegido es de: " + total);
                  System.out.println("Usted tiene un 20% de descuento");
                    descuento = total * 0.20;
                    total = total - descuento; 
                 System.out.println("El costo final de su viaje por las atracciones sera de: " + total);
                
                }
                 
            }else if(reserva == true || niños == true){
              if(niños == true && menores_edad >= 10){
                System.out.println("Gracias por hacer su reserva " + nombre_reserva);
                System.out.println("El costo total, por todas las personas de su paquete, para las atracciones que ha elegido es de: " + total);
                System.out.println("Usted tiene un 10% de descuento");
                System.out.println("Más un 2.5% sobre el descuento");
                  descuento = total * 0.10;
                  total = total - descuento;
                  descuento = total * 0.025;
                  total = total - descuento;
                System.out.println("El costo final de su viaje por las atracciones sera de: " + total);
              }  
                
              System.out.println("Gracias por hacer su reserva " + nombre_reserva);
              System.out.println("El costo total, por todas las personas de su paquete, para las atracciones que ha elegido es de: " + total);
              System.out.println("Usted tiene un 10% de descuento");
                descuento = total * 0.10;
                total = total - descuento;
              System.out.println("El costo final de su viaje por las atracciones sera de: " + total);
              
            }else{
               System.out.println("Gracias por hacer su reserva " + nombre_reserva);
               System.out.print("Usted no tiene un descuento");
               System.out.println("El costo total, por todas las personas de su paquete, para las atracciones que ha elegido es de: " + total);
            }
              
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplemente inicializa la variable menores_edad = 0; Otra cosa si vas a comprobar el valor de las variables booleanas no hace falta indicar == true, puedes hacerlo asi: if(montaña_rusa) o para indicar false, if(!montaña_rusa) añade un signo de admiración !

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu compilador te esta diciendo el problema... la variable esa no tiene ningun valor, porque si no entra al if, entonces no tiene ningun valor. Como te dijeron arriba, inicializala...

Comment: El idioma del sitio es castellano, por ello eliminé lo que habías escrito en gringo